# warning - assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast. WHY?

Tags: pointers, warnings, case, variable-assignment

Why would this give the warning in the title?

```
    char name[10];
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        name[i] = NULL;
```

Answer (score 4):

You want `name[i]=0;` or `name[i]='\0';`. In C, `NULL` is (or, to be more precise, might be) a pointer.

For example, ANSI C permits the following:

```
#define NULL ((void *)0)
```

See the end of [Question 5.9](http://c-faq.com/null/nullor0.html) in the C FAQ for more information. Note that NULL is slightly different in C++.

Answer (score 0):

We don't use **null** for a char, in your case Name[i] is a char,
it is better for u to use the null character **'\0'**.